# Laravel 5.6 Resoure API route with slug

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

I setup installed a json endpoint in Laravel 5.6, i'm looking to use a field other than the ID such as a slug e.g. '/categories/my-slug'. The default uses an id e.g. /categories/1

Route

```
Route::resource('categories', 'CategoryController')->middleware('cors');
```

CategoryController

```
public function show(Category $category)
{
    CategoryResource::withoutWrapping();
    return new CategoryResource($category);
}
```

Category Resource

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'type'          => 'categories',
        'id'            => (string)$this->id,
        'attributes'    => [
            'title' => $this->title,
            'description' => $this->description,
            'status' => $this->status,
            'slug' => $this->slug,
        ]
    ];
}
```

Comment: you are trying to use laravel `slug` helper function? I'm not sure to understand your problem

Answer (score 3):

In your *Category* model add this:

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```

This will make the route model binding work with the category slug instead of the id. You can read more here https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-model-binding